# AFNetworking: Can't get the response string from AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

Anyone?): I'm having a problem that has made me scratch my head for the last 2 hours, and it most likely a very simple stupid thing I'm missing. I Keep getting a building error when I Call the response string from the operation @ AFNetworking... Like there is NO SUCH PROPERTY....

Please Take a look at my code and Explain me what did I Mess up This time :p.. THanks :)

---

```
NSDictionary* paramDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:WebServicemd5Value, WebSermd5Variable, nil]
;
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webServiceURL]];

[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

[httpClient postPath:@"method" parameters:paramDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response data: %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"Reponse String: %@", operation);
```

// Printing operation will show me the operation Dictionary, including the reponse field, // but when I Directly call operation.response, the Compiler won't Build, stating that // "Property not found for AFHTTPRequestOperation".... WEIRDEST THING EVER, right?

```
    NSString* responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]];
    //.. Rest o f my Code....

}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: I'd Like to Simply print the operation.response in the NSLOG instead of the operation itself...

Comment: Are you saying, that when you do NSLog(@"Response object %@",operation.response); - the compiler complains, but when you do NSLog(@"Operation object %@",operation); it prints and it has response as one of its elements. What is your console output.

Comment: Have you tried printing out individual pieces of the operation response?  For instance printing out the status code `NSLog(@"Operation response status = %@", [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:operation.response.statusCode]);`

Comment: @Srinkanth - The Console output is lke a Series of Hexadecimal Numbers.. not Really a Dictionary as I Expected... Thanks

Comment: @Adam Johnson: That's the Thing... I Can't Access operation.response, nor operation.response.statusCode... Weird right? Thanks for the Reply :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hernan, if you expect an `NSDictionary` from a JSON response you should consider using `AFJSONRequestOperation`, because you get a JSON dictionary in your success callback. Anyway, if you want to get a dictionary from your `responseObject`, try to use the following code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error serializing %@", error);
}
NSLog(@"Dictionary %@", JSON);
```

Comment: hi Amb: Thanks for responding Mate... I'll surely be trying the NSJSONSerialization for the Response Object, do I Place it as Is? Or Should I Convert it to UTF8 String? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]]....

Comment: Well, I Tried it, but the Server is Returning me a Response that Does Not Get Parsed OK by the JSON Parser.. I Get:  
2012-12-16 19:17:14.536 Vidac[3561:19d03] Error serializing Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x94917d0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
Printing description of responseObject:
<59397142 7871677a ...... >
2012-12-16 19:17:42.592 Vidac[3561:19d03] Dictionary (null)

Comment: It seems that your server side is not returning a valid JSON object propertly, or that you have some problems with encoding. Try to copy and paste your JSON string response and check with a validator if everything is OK. Also, check NSJSONSerialization options.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the response string is inside the "operation" object, so something like:

```
...
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", operation.responseString);
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

While attempting to retrieve content from meetup.com api using AFNetworking (kudos to Mattt T. for a great framework, btw), ran into the same error - "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 3840)". Realized that the issue I was having was with the response data containing a Swedish character 'Ø', resulting in the parsing error.  The solution was to include the header 'Accept-Charset: utf-8' in the initialization of the AFNetworking client. Fixed!

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept-Charset" value:@"utf-8"];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: "Ø" is danish. The Swedish version would be "Ö". :)